# Using custom tags for dispplay image or video in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, tags

I added button to my form like this to my simple content management system. I write articles etc. So I want to add pictures and videos also. And I want to add them using by custom tags

```
    function formatText (el,tagstart,tagend) { 

    if (el.setSelectionRange) {
    el.value = el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart) + tagstart + el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd) + tagend + el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length)
    }
    else {
    var selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;

    if (selectedText != "") { 
        var newText = tagstart + selectedText + tagend; 
        document.selection.createRange().text = newText; 
    } 

    }



} 


<form name="my_form"> 
<textarea name="my_textarea" id="mytext"></textarea><br /> 
<input type="button" value="IMAGE" onclick="formatText (document.getElementById('mytext'),'[IMAGE]','[/IMAGE]');" />
```

This is add [IMAGE] [/IMAGE] tags into my text area, and I want to show image links between this tags after submitting form. Same way, I want to add [VIDEO] [/VIDEO] tags and if I write youtube links between these tags, then show video when showing page.

How can I do that?

Comment: To show a youtube video, you'll have to insert youtube's custom embed code. See http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780.

Comment: How do I integrate with custom tags?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by custom tags.

Comment: How can I auto identify  [VIDEO]http://www.youtube.com?vvddee [/VIDEO] as a video file? Please read my question again

Comment: So you want to search through the html for [VIDEO]<url>[/VIDEO] and embed the youtube video referred to?

Comment: Yes, also I want to do same thing for any image file between [IMAGE]http://www.www.com/ggg.jpg[/IMAGE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work. See the comments for more explanation.

```
//The data for this variable would be read from a database, user input, etc.
$content = "Non augue, ultrices[VIDEO]www.youtube.com/?vvddee[/VIDEO] ut elementum natoque tempor placerat. Egestas, penatibus urna, dis risus habitasse. Rhoncus augue urna porta, enim cum risus eu tortor in, p[IMAGE]images/abcde.png[/IMAGE]lacerat rhoncus mus tortor? Nec, magnis, enim elementum non urna eros augue, ridiculus porta dapibus? Parturient, dictumst nunc vel turpis! Eu eros vel tempor cum in.";

//Replace custom video tag with youtube embed
preg_match_all('/\[VIDEO\](https?:\/\/)?(www.)?youtube.com(\/watch\?v=|\/?\?)?(\w*)\[\/VIDEO\]/im', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $match){
    $content = str_replace($match[0],'<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$match[4].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',$content);
}

//Replace custom image tag with html image tag
preg_match_all('/\[IMAGE\](.*)\[\/IMAGE\]/im', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $match){
    $content = str_replace($match[0],'<img src="'.$match[1].'"></image>',$content);
}
echo $content;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I do this using by php functions? This is not working in my code, matches gives error.

Comment: @Seyhan Finally got around to testing my code and found/fixed a bunch of errors. See my updated answer for fixed code and a demo.

Comment: Thank you jdwire, looks perfect

Comment: Also, I want to learn about how can I define preg_match_all for removing http:// watch?v= from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFM link

Comment: @Seyhan Try changing the regex string to `/\[VIDEO\](https?:\/\/)?(www.)?youtube.com(\/watch\?v=|\/?\?)?(\w*)\[\/VIDEO\]/im` and see if that works.

Comment: it opens youtube but there is nothing to play. Just black screen.

Comment: @Seyhan What url are you putting in your `[VIDEO]` tags?

Comment: Seems to be working fine when I put that in my `$content` variable. If you use your browser's developer tools, can you see what the `src` of the iframe is?

Comment: I did it again but I just saw black video screen, video is not start to play. I don't use developer tools, if you suggest me, I try that

Comment: What is the `src` of the iframe? Without that information, I can't continue to help you.

Comment: What is the actual src that was sent from the server? Use your browser's dev tools.

Comment: <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed//watch?v=" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: I changed '.$match[3] to '.$match[4] and it works :) Thanks for all

Comment: @Seyhan Ah, I had changed that on my local test script but had forgotten to mention that change to you. That explains why it worked for me but not for you. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: The OP ended up clarifying that a PHP code answer was wanted (see my other answer). Leaving this here in case others want a JS solution.**

Having a hard time testing this code (jsfiddle is not working for me), but I think this should work:

For a youtube video:

```
var el = document.getElementById('<your element id>');
while(true){
    var match = '/\[VIDEO\](https?:\/\/)?(www.)?youtube.com(\/watch\?v=|\/?\?)?(\w*)\[\/VIDEO\]/im.exec(el.innerHTML);
    if(match==null)break;
    el.innerHTML=el.innerHTML.replace(match[0],'<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+match[1]+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}​
```

You'd want to do something similar for an image. Note that if you have any references to any elements within the element they will be broken. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will test this, so may be <img scr=""> html code is work for images if I can include it to codes

Comment: Right, to make it work with images you would just have to replace the code specific to images with code specific to videos. If you let me know if the code for video works, I can try to edit my answer to include code for images.

Comment: What is the element id? and how can I add this code into view content page? is this a function?

Comment: What element are your custom tags going to be in? Anywhere in the whole body? If so, then change `document.getElementById('<your element id>');` to `document.body`.

Comment: Are you wanting to run the code on the server or on the client?

Comment: I want to run my codes on the server, I write a php codes and just want to add some custom tags for attaching images and videos into article.

Comment: Got it. The code I posted is JavaScript. Let me post a new answer using PHP. Did you mean to tag your question with the php tag? Also do you have a variable in php with code that you want to replace the custom tags?